# JavaScript - Algorithm exercise involving string iteration and manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex, string, loops

I have this algorithm exercise below. I did understand all details about the instructor s' answer. With one exception, the importance of this line code below:

```
const firstConsonant = letters.splice(0,1)[0]
```

To be more specific, I didn't understand why the instructor put this item `[0]` on. Because it works equally without it, with the line of code like this:

```
const firstConsonant = letters.splice(0,1)
```

**Here is the exercise:**

**Objective**

Translate the provided string to pig latin.

Pig Latin takes the first consonant (or consonant cluster) of
an English word, moves it to the end of the word and suffixes an "ay".

If a word begins with a vowel you just add "way" to the end.

Input strings are guaranteed to be English words in all lowercase.

Example

pigLatin("glove") should return "oveglay".
pigLatin("eight") should return "eightway".

**Instructor's Answer:**

```
function solution(str) {
  const letters = str.split('')
  const vowelRegex = /[aeiou]/

 if(vowelRegex.test(str[0])) { 
    return `${str}way`
  }

 

  while (true) {
   if(!vowelRegex.test(letters[0])) {   
      const firstConsonant = letters.splice(0,1)[0]   
      letters.push(firstConsonant)
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

 

  str = letters.join('') + 'ay'

  return str
}

console.log(solution('glove')) //oveglay
```

Comment: `letters.splice(0,1)[0]` gets the first *character*, `letters.splice(0,1)` gets an *array* with one character in it.

Comment: Thank you, But why the both options returns the same result?

Comment: Because of a quirk of coercing arrays into strings. If you have `["a"]` and turn it into a string, it produces `"a"`. In that respect it can be interchanged with the string `"a"`. However, that's ONLY applicable to arrays with a single element in them and ONLY when using the string coercion. You should not rely on this behaviour and in general should only work with the data type you expect - in this case everything else is a string, so you should stick to strings.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you show me any example that this could be wrong? For me to understand the importance of [0] in the splice?

Comment: Again in *this* case it works, however, if you have `["a", "b"].toString()` you'd get `"a,b"` not `"ab"`. Doing something because it offers an extremely miniscule convenience in only one case, is not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splice method will return an array of the elements removed. Appending [0] will extract the first (and in this case, the only) element that was removed.

Comment: Thank you, But why the both options returns the same result?